yticklabels left alignment
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                xbar,
                title={\tiny T5-base},
                axis background/.style={fill=grey!5},
                bar width=5pt,
                ytick=data,
                yticklabels={EPT+ReLU, EPT+Sigmoid, EPT+Tanh, EPT+LayerNorm, EPT+residual, EPT+dropout, EPT},
                yticklabel style={text, align=right}, 
                xlabel={SuperGLUE avg score},
                xmin=20,
                xmax=75,
                nodes near coords,
                nodes near coords align=horizontal,
                ymajorgrids=true,
                xmajorgrids=true,
                ytick align=outside,
                xtick align=outside,
                xtick pos=left,
                ytick pos=left,
                grid style={white!50},
            ]
            \addplot coordinates {(20.9685, 0) (30.9, 1) (51.09, 2) (62.3, 3) (66.4, 4) (66.7, 5) (67.8, 6)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



I want to align yticklabel to the left such as:

i used yticklabel style={text, align=left},  but it doesn't work.

align=left works if you set also the text width
yticklabel style={text width=2.8cm, align=left},

Full example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                xbar,
                title={\tiny T5-base},
                axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
                bar width=5pt,
                ytick=data,
                yticklabels={EPT+ReLU, EPT+Sigmoid, EPT+Tanh, EPT+LayerNorm, EPT+residual, EPT+dropout, EPT},
                yticklabel style={text width=2.8cm, align=left},
                xlabel={SuperGLUE avg score},
                xmin=20,
                xmax=75,
                nodes near coords,
                nodes near coords align=horizontal,
                ymajorgrids=true,
                xmajorgrids=true,
                ytick align=outside,
                xtick align=outside,
                xtick pos=left,
                ytick pos=left,
                grid style={white!50},
            ]
            \addplot coordinates {(20.9685, 0) (30.9, 1) (51.09, 2) (62.3, 3) (66.4, 4) (66.7, 5) (67.8, 6)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


